# How do I input into a method that takes Arrays?

Tags: java

```
    public class Survey
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] survey = {1,2,6,4,8,5,9,7,8,10,1,6,3,8,6,10,3,8,2,7,6,5,7,6,8,6,7,5,6,6,5,6,7,5,6,4,8,6,8,10};
        int length = survey.length;
        int undivided = 0, avg;
        for(int loop = length -1; loop>=0; loop--)
        {
            int add = survey[loop];
            System.out.println(add);
            undivided = add + undivided;        
        }
        System.out.println(undivided);
        avg = (undivided/length);
        System.out.println("The average score for the cafeteria was:" + avg);
        System.out.println(countFrequencies(survey[3]));
    }

    public static void countFrequencies(int input[]) { 
        int n = input.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            input[i]--;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            input[input[i] % n] += n;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println((i + 1) + " " + input[i] / n);
            input[i] = input[i] % n + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

How do I input into the method of frequencies... It doesn't work. I don't know what else I can try but it seems like theres a bit of an issue when I try to input anything. It wont properly run.

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
The method countFrequencies(int[]) in the type Survey is not applicable for the arguments (int)
    at Survey.main(Survey.java:18)
```

Comment: You don't get that error for that code, because you're passing no parameters to `countFrequencies()`, not an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

- `survey` is `int[]`
- `survey[3]` is `int`
- `countFrequencies()` expects `int[]` parameter, but got `survey[3]` which is `int`